# Disable Bootstrap from a custom button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

How can I disable the **Bootstrap** from resizing my button inside of a `div` element. It is an order button and it gets almost invisible if used in mobile device.

It is actually an `a` tag with an `img` inside of it.

Here's the following script:

```
<div class="buttonImage" style="color:green" style="font-size: 2">
    <a href="transaction.html?totalprice=3000">
        <img src="img/orderbutton.png" width="15%" height="15%" onmouseover="this.src='img/orderbuttonhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/orderbutton.png'" alt="OrderButton"/>
    </a>
    <label class="cash">3000 Points</label>
</div>
```

Is there any suggestion to not resize this button? My `div` element will not be resized, but the buttons will instead. And also, the most left button resizes first before the middle and right button (there are 3 divs horizontally, 6 divs vertically).

Comment: Have you tried assigning the size for the button through CSS and using `!important`?

Comment: No, because I have not set the button (or image/link) an ID or class. Should I?

Comment: Not sure if it will override Bootstrap or not, but worth a try.

Comment: Did not work :(

Comment: Use inline CSS and give it a fixed width! also, inline css has the maximum priority! Also, assigning multiple style="" will not work for you! You need to correct that as well

Comment: You have => `<img src="img/orderbutton.png" width="15%"` with no apparent other css... of course it is going to resize on `window.width` change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width="15%" height="15%"` and add the class of `img-responsive` and apply mobile classes to the parent div for mobile screen's.

```
<div class='col-lg-2 col-xs-12'>
    <div class="buttonImage" style="color:green" style="font-size: 2">
        <a href="transaction.html?totalprice=3000">
            <img class='img-responsive' src="img/orderbutton.png" alt="OrderButton"/>
        </a>
        <label class="cash">3000 Points</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This format will ensure that when your viewing the block from anything that is smaller than desktop at two columns it will get the max width so it's not tiny.